# same mercurial account on two computers, fail to push

Tags: mercurial, repository

I'm using easy mercurial. I have changed a computer, but still use same account for my repository. when I pushing things to my repository, it always failed.

The prompt said: A Mercurial command failed to run correctly. This may indicate an installation problem or some other problem with EasyMercurial.

More Detail showed: warning: code.soundsoftware.ac.uk certificate with fingerprint 74:51:c7:c4:9b:85:de:05:02:2f:9f:ec:7f:16:25:4c:68:48:74:7c not verified (check host finger prints or web.cacerts config setting)

I use windows 7 and the installation is correct. I re-installed it many times, but it always failed to push.  Then I used my old computer, re-installed the Mercurial, but it also fail to push. But I can push things correctly in my old computer before I  uninstalled Mercurial in it. And I didn't find solution in wiki for my problem. Could anyone help me? What should I do? That's an emergency, I need to solve this as soon as possible!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message it seems that mercurial is not trusting the host you are trying to push to.

Try add this to your .hg/hgrc file in the top level of your repository (if it doesn't exist, create a file called hgrc (no extension) in the .hg directory and open it with a text editor and add this):

```
[hostfingerprints]
code.soundsoftware.ac.uk = 74:51:c7:c4:9b:85:de:05:02:2f:9f:ec:7f:16:25:4c:68:48:74:7c
```

If that works, you may want to add the same to %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini if you are pushing to that server from multiple repositories.

reference: [mercurial hgrc files hostfingerprints](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hostfingerprints)